# Correct HTTP verb for updating cache for REST Api

Tags: rest, http, caching, http-verbs, acceptverbs

I am developing RESTful Api micro service which is cache all data in memory (and update it every `n` minutes from persistent storage). Service has an api for immediate cache updating `/update-cache`.

What is best http verb for updating cache?

`GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `PATCH` or i need to create some custom verb

Comment: If you don't want neither to send any kind of "body" nor explicitly update any resource you should use GET

Comment: This is what I thought. But specification required `GET` to be safe:

> An HTTP method is safe if it doesn't alter the state of the server. In other words, a method is safe if it leads to a read-only operation.

© https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/safe

Which seems not quite true to me for cache update operation

Comment: If you want to follow "specifications" you should not use REST to call the service/function. REST is by definition for operating on resources (and "update-..." is not a resource - it is a verb). You can try something like `DELETE /cache` but for me it looks a bit "exotic"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your proposing is not really RESTful, it's more like an RPC-style operation. For this `POST` is fine.